# Express + socket.io: socket.io client script is 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

This is driving me crazy... while I have a working version of Express + Socket.io, I can't seem to reproduce it with out-of-the-box NPM installs in a new project folder. Can anyone point out what I'm missing...? Here's my process:

I create a `node_modules` folder in my project directory (`pwd`), then do:

```
npm install express
npm install socket.io
```

Running those two commands puts the packages in my project's `node_modules` folder as expected. Now I set up my server with the following:

```
var express = require('express'),
    server = express.createServer().use( express.static(__dirname+'./public') ).listen( 8080 ),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

My `public` folder contains static assets for my application. My public index HTML page includes a script tag for:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Finally, I run my server script and go to the application in a web browser. My static public files are all served properly, however I get a 404 for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`. Now, I can swap in an `express` package from another old project and have this whole system work. Somehow that package instance is configured differently, but I can't figure out how to reproduce that. The Express website mentions something about installing dependencies, although running `npm install -d` doesn't seem to help (is there a specific `pwd` that I need to be in while running `npm install -d`?). I figure I must be missing something important about configuring a new Express instance after installing it with NPM.

Thanks for any and all insight!

Comment: What version of express and socket.io is installing? I just went through the steps you did, and both static assets and socket.io.js is serving fine.

Comment: the client side socket.io.js is generated dynamically, it shouldn't have anything to do with your express static server.  

Can I get more information about the route that is failing?

Check to what happens if you go to http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js or http://localhost:8000/socket.io/  (replace 8000 with the port number you are running your app on)

Comment: Ditto what Timothy said...it works on my machine. Although in Windows I had to change the path to the static files as follow: __dirname+'/public' (removed the dot)

Answer (score 7):

Okay, so my example was actually an abbreviation of my code, and that example code does actually work. My real code with problems was a bit more cluttered, like so:

```
var server = express.createServer();

server
    .use( server.router )
    .use( express.static(__dirname+'/../public') )
    .get('/api', function(req, res) {
        res.write('API');
    });

server.listen(8080);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

I fixed the above code by doing the following:

```
server = server.listen(8080);
```

Apparently the `listen` command wraps the server object with some additional functionality. My originally posted shorthand example actually does work because `listen` is chained onto the final return into the server variable. Interesting little nuance.

Comment: Glad to help! This is really odd issue which I'm still a little mystified by. Does anyone know what the .listen() function actually returns? I would assume it to return a reference to the http.Server object on which is was invoked (to facilitate chaining). The object it returns seems to have some similar methods to an http.Server object, but is not identical. Unfortunately, documentation doesn't specify the nature of returns.